# Error 403 when cloning an AWS CodeCommit repository from EC2 instance

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-codecommit

I'm trying to do exactly the same thing as this document I've found here : https://blog.0x427567.com/how-to-clone-aws-codecommit-repository-from-ec2-instance-99e4abfda1a1

I have created a new CodeCommit repository (empty) and I'm trying to clone it from a EC2 instance with a role assigned to it containing the permission "AWSCodeCommitFullAccess". Maybe I need a ssh key or something, but that's weird that the guide doesn't mention it.

On the EC instance I used the following command (with AWS CLI and pip already installed) :

```
git config --global credential.helper '!aws codecommit credential-helper $@'
git config --global credential.UseHttpPath true    
pip install git-remote-codecommit
```

Then cloning with either :

```
git clone https://git-codecommit.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/[REPO]
```

or

```
git clone codecommit::eu-west-3://[REPO]
```

Gives me the same error :

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/[Repo]/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

**Edit :**

I have manage to clone my repository, the issue came that I was using a user that had a .aws/credentials file that override my role permissions. And thoses credentials didn't have any access to CodeCommit repo.

Comment: The AWS documentation is truly cryptic about that, if anyone has a suggestion

Comment: A "403" error means you're using https, not ssh. Git chooses the *protocol* based on the *URL*, so if you want to try ssh, you'll need an `ssh://` URL (or equivalent) instead of an `https://` URL. Not having used AWS Codecommit, I can't speak to that side of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure there is enough info to provide a definitive answer but my guess is that since `eu-west-3 (Paris)` is [*not* explicitly mentioned as a supported default region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-https-unixes.html#setting-up-https-unixes-account) , you may need to update the version of botocore on your server.

The reason I ask is because you shouldn't need to provide the region name if the server and repository are in the same region:

```bash
# you should be able to just do this
$ git clone codecommit://MyDemoRepo
```

Turning up git's log level may provide you enough info to resolve as well:

```bash
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git clone codecommit::eu-west-3://MyRepo
...
```

---

Additional info that can help provide a better answer:

1. Is the server you're running the git commands from in the same region as the repository (eu-west-3)?
2. Making sure the role assigned to your ec2 instance is correct:

```bash
$ aws sts get-caller-identity
...
```

3. What versions of tools/os are you using i.e. the output of the following commands:

```bash
# check the OS of the instance
$ cat /etc/os-release
...

# make sure semi recent version of git is used
$ git --version
...

# make sure semi recent of aws-cli is used (preferably v2)
$ aws --version
...

# make sure there aren't more than 1 aws-cli installed
$ type -a aws
...

#  check pip version
$ pip --version
...

# list packages w/versions installed by pip
$ pip freeze
...

# show info about the credential helper package
$ pip show git-remote-codecommit
...
```

Comment: I have managed to do it, it was coming from a user issue (see post Edit)